# MVC 3 Navigate to Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Sorry for the stupid question , but how can I implement the following thing ?

I Have a controller Named ServerMonitor , It has only one Action

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content(WebUtility.ServerID);
        }
```

How can I execute the following Action typing

http://mydom.com/ServerMonitor instead of **http://mydom.com/ServerMonitor/Index**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `{action}` parameter in the route URL default to `"index"`.
The standard route defined in the ASP.Net MVC template already does this.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute
(
"RouteName",
{controller}",
new{action = "index", id = "UrlParameter.optional"
);
```

I think this is basically what you need.